# Printscreen shortcut in Windows - Printscreen button no longer works

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way of taking a screenshot without pressing the PrintScreen button since the button on my keyboard is broken?

Comment: Under Windows Vista / 7, the Snipping Tool will do the job.

Comment: You can install something like Greenshot. That gives a lot more control over the screenshot, as compared to just the print-screen button!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done through ON SCREEN KEYBOARD

Steps to get your ON SCREEN KEYBOARD

1. Start - Programs - Accessories - Accessibility - on screen keyboard

or

Go to Run , Type osk and the ON SCREEN KEYBOARD is yours. Just Click on PSC Tab on your ON SCREEN KEYBOARD with the mouse to capture the image.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 and higher, it is the Snipping Tool. There is no accessibility option for it by default. Make sure that the area you want to snip is the area that you are looking at, and not this page or it will try to snip this page.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the On Screen Keyboard (OSK) still works in win 8.1  ... the OSK is different to the win 8.1 pop up keyboard and includes all the missing keys including PrtScn.

To make OSK easy to use (first time only) press the Windows key/icon then press the search icon (top right of the start screen) and just type OSK as the search term ... OSK will pop up as a search result ... right click(or long press) the OSK icon and attach it to the task bar for access from desktop.

Then to capture a desktop screen or window image press the OSK icon on the taskbar, then press PrtScn -- or even better click any window to set the focus and then click ALT then PrtScn to capture the selected window.

Its probably best to reduce the size of the OSK window and move it out of the way of the selected window as it will be also be captured as part of the image, if it overlaps the area of interest.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tidy little free program called ScreenPresso, have a go with that one. http://www.screenpresso.com. I realise it's not exactly what you were looking for but I find it works brilliantly, there's an inbuilt image editor all in a taskbar button.